# System.webserver has invalid child element "cors"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

This is a completed project from my team, but i dun know why i getting this .
[image: cors in web.config]

In my config.cs. This already enable cors . cors already installed in Nuget package:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        
        SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        traceWriter.IsVerbose = true;
        traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Debug;

        // Enable Web API routes by attribute
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
```

Comment: What docs did you read to suggest you put that `cors` element there in that web.config?

Comment: No, This the completed project i cloned from my team repo. But they said that it's okay for them.

Comment: Have you installed the module? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Comment: Yes, I have installed.

Comment: Maybe reboot your machine - since it doesn't think you have.

Comment: Have you manage to resolve this, I have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same behaviour with several of our *Visual Studio 2022* and *VS Code* solutions. It seems the *Visual Studio IntelliSense* isn't updated when you install the *Cors NuGet Package*, so this warning is shown when you view the **web.config** file. However, it works as expected if the solution is published to an *IIS* instance that has the required extensions installed. Note that no warning is shown in the build output either.

Comment: How to enable CORS in IIS Express (the default webserver the Visual Studio runs in debug mode)?

Comment: This link has the relevant information, but in case it gets lost, just search for IIS Cors Install, and you'll find the appropriate page at Microsoft.com. [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module)

Comment: Hello SiBrit, related to VS it was also answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77045371/cors-how-to-allow-preflight-requests-with-iis-express-vs-debugger-and-with-crede