# CORS how to allow preflight requests with IIS Express VS Debugger and with credentials (authentication)

Tags: authentication, cors, iis-express, asp.net-core-7.0

I have enabled CORS as follows

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddCors();

var app = builder.Build();
 
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true));
 
app.UseAuthentication();
```

**Client**

```
const axiosClient = axios.create({
   baseURL: configuration.apiUrl,
   headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
   withCredentials: true });
```

**Server (LaunchSettings.json)**

```
 "CustomProfile": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60737",
      "sslPort": 44358
    }
  }
```

When I call

```
// Get records list
axiosClient.get('records').then((res: AxiosResponse) => res.data)
```

I get Status Code 200 with the data and the user was authenticated at the backend.

But when I call

```
// Create new record
axiosClient.post('record', createCommand).then((res: AxiosResponse) => res.data)
```

I get following error message

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44358/api/records' from
> origin 'https://localhost:44414' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

any idea what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Preflight requests are anonymous, so Windows authentication simply blocks all of them and leads to the issue. You have to use IIS CORS module on IIS or IIS Express to handle that properly.

Comment: IIS Express is started from Visual Studio. How to enable anonymous preflights? When I setup "anonymousAuthentication": true, than the authentication is not done at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [CORS setup](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) on the server side seems mostly correct, allowing any origin and credentials. However, the [preflight request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch) (which is automatically sent by browsers when you make a "non-simple" request, like a `POST` request with JSON body) seems to be failing.

Meaning, the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-responses) is not being sent in the preflight response, which is necessary to allow the actual request from a different origin.

From [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77045371/cors-how-to-allow-preflight-requests-with-iis-express-vs-debugger-and-with-crede#comment135823982_77045371):

> Preflight requests are anonymous, so Windows authentication simply blocks all of them and leads to the issue. You have to use IIS CORS module on IIS or IIS Express to handle that properly.

You see that suggestion in "[How to authorize CORS preflight request on IIS with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361880/6309)", using the [CORS Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module).
You will need to enable the CORS Module via the Webconfig:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="https://localhost:44414" allowCredentials="true">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true"/>
        <allowMethods>
          <add method="GET"/>
          <add method="POST"/>
          <add method="OPTIONS"/>
        </allowMethods>
      </add>
    </cors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The order of middleware in ASP.NET Core can affect their behavior. And specify the allowed origins instead of allowing any origin. That is a good practice to prevent potential security issues.

Change your CORS setup to:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(x => x
    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44414")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());
    
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Using browser developer tools, inspect the preflight (OPTIONS) request and response to see what headers are being sent and received. Ensure that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is included in the response with the correct value.

---

> When I add the web.config file the CORS element is highlighted as invalid and website throw HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error.

If IIS Express does not support the CORS module, and it only can be configured in the full version of IIS. That might be the reason why you are experiencing the HTTP Error 500.19 when trying to add the CORS configuration to the `web.config` file.
There is an old 2013 article "[Enabling CORS in IISExpress](https://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2013-09-16-enabling-cors-in-iisexpress/)" from [Jonathan Channon](https://twitter.com/jchannon) which could help (at the time)

But given this limitation, we might need to revert to configuring CORS directly within your ASP.NET Core application, which you have already started doing in your `Program.cs` file.
Since you are encountering issues with Windows Authentication blocking anonymous preflight requests issued by browsers, you could try and disable Windows Authentication during the preflight request and then re-enabling it for the actual request.

Make sure the middleware in `Program.cs` is ordered correctly. The `UseCors` method should come before `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` methods.

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(x => x
    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44414")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Considering the limitations with IIS Express and Windows Authentication, you might need to handle preflight requests manually in your ASP.NET Core application. That involves creating a middleware to intercept OPTIONS requests and return a 200 OK response before Windows Authentication is applied.

You can create a middleware like this:

```cs
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Method.Equals("OPTIONS", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    return next();
});
```

Place this middleware at the very beginning of your middleware pipeline, even before the `UseCors` middleware.

After implementing these changes, test your setup by running your application in debug mode through Visual Studio, and try making OPTIONS, GET, and POST requests from your client application to verify if the issue is resolved.
(Do not forget to clear your browser's cache or try in an incognito/private window to avoid any caching issues while testing.)

By focusing on configuring CORS correctly within your ASP.NET Core application and ensuring that preflight requests can successfully bypass Windows Authentication, you should be able to develop a solution that works in your development environment using IIS Express through Visual Studio.

---

> I tried it, but the request doesn't seem to reach the backend at all, and it is stopped by the browser. I also tried to follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api, and added ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 handler to `web.config` but the same issue, the request is blocked by the browser.
>
> Probably it is because I have `"anonymousAuthentication": false` in `launchSettings.json`. When I switch it to true, it starts to work, but no Authentication is done (`HttpContext.User.Identity` contains null values for following POST request).

Given your updated circumstances, one potential solution could be to permit anonymous authentication for preflight (`OPTIONS`) requests while still enforcing Windows Authentication for other types of requests. This approach would mean configuring your application to allow anonymous authentication but then selectively applying Windows Authentication in your ASP.NET Core middleware.

First, in your `launchSettings.json`, enable anonymous authentication:

```json
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    ...
}
```

Then, create a custom middleware to handle authentication for requests other than OPTIONS:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Method.Equals("OPTIONS", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Allow preflight request to proceed anonymously
        await next();
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure Windows Authentication is applied to other requests
        var isAuthenticated = context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        
        if (!isAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
});
```

Make sure this middleware is placed correctly in your middleware pipeline - it should come after `UseAuthentication` but before endpoints are mapped:

```cs
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.Use(async (context, next) => 
{ 
    // ... (middleware content as above)
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // ... (your endpoint mappings)
});
```

Finally, update your CORS policy to allow credentials and specify the allowed origins appropriately, as you had before:

```cs
app.UseCors(x => x
    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44414")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());
```

By using this approach, you should be able to satisfy the browser's CORS requirements while still enforcing Windows Authentication for your endpoints during development.
This will create a scenario where preflight requests are allowed without authentication, but actual requests are authenticated correctly.

That remains a workaround for development, however, and might not be suitable for a production environment where more robust security measures would be necessary.

Comment: I do not understand that. My question is related to IIS Express running from Visual Studio in debug mode. How do I install the CORS module in Visual Studio? Or is the solution only related to the full installation of the IIS Express service in the operating system? When I add the `web.config` file the CORS element is highlighted as invalid and website throw `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error`. This issue is only related to development environment, not staging or production.

Comment: @Muflix True, my initial answer was more geared to a full-fledged IIS installation. I have edited the answer to propose an alternative approach.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the idea. I tried it, but the request doesn't seem to reach the backend at all and it is stopped by the browser. I also tried to follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api and added `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0` handler
to `web.config` but the same issue, the request is blocked by the browser 

Comment: Probably it is because I have `"anonymousAuthentication": false` in launchSettings.json. When I switch it to true it starts to work but no Authentication is done (HttpContext.User.Identity contains null values for following POST request).

Comment: Great, it works  thank you very much for the comprehensive answer! 